# understanding cardinal numbers arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I have a question about notation in a book I'm reading on set theory
and beside of my question I will be glad for a recommendation for a good book that explains well cardinal numbers arithmetic.

If we define that $\kappa $ is a cardinal number if $\kappa$ is an ordinal number such that for every $\alpha <\kappa$ there is no $f:\alpha\to\kappa$ that is surjective, 
in what sense for two infinite cardinal numbers $\kappa$ and $\gamma$ , we have that $\kappa +\gamma=\kappa\cdot\gamma=\max \{\kappa,\gamma\}$? Is this ordinal arithmetic? 
or is it arithmetic in the sense of bijections of disjoint unions and products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cardinal arithmetic, not ordinal arithmetic, so yes, it's all about existence of bijections related to disjoint unions and products.

One additional comment: $\kappa \cdot \gamma = \max \{ \kappa,\gamma \}$ requires choice to be proven for general infinite cardinals.

Comment: Ian: $\omega <\omega+1$, and yet $\omega+\omega+1>\omega+1$. What you described are the (infinite) *indecomposable* ordinals, which coincide with the (infinite) ordinal powers of $\omega $: The ordinals of the form $\omega^\alpha $ with $\alpha\ge1$.

Comment: For well-ordered infinite cardinals (as here) that $\kappa+\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\} $ does *not* use choice.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo For your first point, that's valid, I edited accordingly. For your second point, I didn't say anything to the contrary.